# How to retain the rotation position of objective in android

Tags: android, rotation, android-animation

I use the following code to rotate an imageview .. 
How to keep the last position of the image after rotation ?

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:toDegrees="-90"  />

</set>
```

I mean : I don't want the `imageview` go back to the original position after the rotation

Comment: no i mean another thing , see the edit ..

Answer (score -1):

include in your rotate element:

```
android:fillAfter="true"
```

like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true" >

    <rotate
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:toDegrees="-90"  />

</set>
```

Comment: include in your what and where?